# Use forall instead of filter on List[A]

Tags: scala, filter, pattern-matching, tuples, forall

Am trying to determine whether or not to display an overtime game display flag in weekly game results report.

Database game results table has 3 columns (p4,p5,p6) that represent potential overtime game period score total ( for OT, Double OT, and Triple OT respectively). These columns are mapped to Option[Int] in application layer.

Currently I am filtering through game result teamA, teamB pairs, but really I just want to know if an OT game exists of any kind (vs. stepping through the collection).

```
def overtimeDisplay(a: GameResult, b: GameResult) = {
  val isOT = !(List(a,b).filter(_.p4.isDefined).filter(_.p5.isDefined).filter(_.p6.isDefined).isEmpty)
  if(isOT) {
    <b class="b red">
    {List( ((a.p4,a.p5,a.p6),(b.p4,b.p5,b.p6)) ).zipWithIndex.map{
      case( ((Some(_),None,None), (Some(_),None,None)), i)=> "OT"
      case( ((Some(_),Some(_),None), (Some(_),Some(_),None )), i)=> "Double OT"
      case( ((Some(_),Some(_),Some(_)), (Some(_),Some(_),Some(_) )), i)=> "Triple OT"
    }}
    </b>
  }
  else scala.xml.NodeSeq.Empty
}
```

Secondarily, the determination of which type of overtime to display, currently that busy pattern match (which, looking at it now, does not appear cover all the scoring scenarios), could probably be done in a more functional/concise manner.

Feel free to lay it down if you have the better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the initial code correctly, but here is an idea:

```
val results = List(a, b).map(r => Seq(r.p4, r.p5, r.p6).flatten)
val isOT = results.exists(_.nonEmpty)
val labels = IndexedSeq("", "Double ", "Triple ")
results.map(p => labels(p.size - 1) + "OT")
```

Turning score column to flat list in first line is crucial here. You have `GameResult(p4: Option[Int], p5: Option[Int], p6: Option[Int])` which you can map to `Seq[Option[Int]]`: `r => Seq(r.p4, r.p5, r.p6)` and later flatten to turn `Some[Int]` to `Int` and get rid of `None`. This will turn `Some(42), None, None` into `Seq(42)`.

Comment: +1 wow, even better, exists on nonEmpty, awesome, AND, to compress that pattern match down to basically nothing, there should be a +10 option ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes: my bad, change to: `labels(p.size - 1)`

Comment: right, already did, and got an index out of bounds exception. Could be data set on my end, need to verify. Also need an if(isOT) in there, otherwise every game is displayed as OT, not the case ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes: right, the size of `p` can be anything between `0` and `3` but if you exclude empty (`if(isOT)`), everything should work. Sorry for the mistake, as I said I did not fully understood the domain.

Comment: no worries, what you've done already is pretty incredible. I am seeing List(), List(0), List(1), and List(1,1) as results with if(isOT), so something may be amiss with the dataset (assume that empty List should not be possible when if "results.exists(_.nonEmpty)" returns true)

Comment: got the double OT display issue sorted (dataset has some nulls that should have been 0 for OT period score). In the end, "results.map(p => labels(p.size-1) + "OT").max" does the trick

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this:

```
val isOT = !(List(a,b).filter(_.p4.isDefined).filter(_.p5.isDefined).filter(_.p6.isDefined).isEmpty)
```

This can be rewritten using `exists` instead of `filter`.  I would rewrite it as follows:

```
List(a, b).exists(x => x.p4.isDefined && x.p5.isDefined && x.p6.isDefined)
```

In addition to using `exists`, I am combining the three conditions you passed to the filters into a single anonymous function.

In addition, I don't know why you're using `zipWithIndex` when it doesn't seem as though you're using the index in the `map` function afterwards.  It could be removed entirely.

Comment: +1, ah, exists, I see. re; zipWithIndex, yah, with plain zip the compiler complained about passed in List[Tuple3], was easier to List[(Tuple3,Tuple3)] on zipWithIndex.